# Escape characters when executing powershell command in batch script

Tags: batch, powershell

I want to execute powershell command and put it in batch variable

The command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('powershell ^(Get-ChildItem ""\dir\"" -Name | sort-object {\[regex\]::Replace^($_,^'\d+^',{$args\[0\].Value.PadLeft^(20^)}^)} | select -last 1^) ') do set output=%%i
```

It can't be executed due special character. In addition, I can't pause the window so it closes before I can see what is the problem.

I think the problem is with the pipe "|", because the following command does work

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('powershell ^(Get-ChildItem ""\dir\"" -Name^) ') do set output=%%i
```

I tried to add `^` and `""` before pipe, doesn't work. Can you spot the problem?

Comment: "I want to execute powershell command and put it in batch variable" - why? Just run the PowerShell command you want directly from a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Use **three carets** before pipe as `^^^|`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a backtick as the escape character. I assume you are trying to fix the `""\dir\""` part of the command? A simple escaping example below:

```
PS A:\> Write-Host "`"Use the `` as an escape character to place a `" inside other `"s.`""
```

Returns:

```
"Use the ` as an escape character to place a " inside other "s."
```

I can't see the pipe causing the problem... Redirecting your output (`1>&2`) may be helpful.